# Manage multiple Jlabel's events

Tags: java, events, jlabel, actionlistener, cardlayout

I have a left Panel with multiples Jlabels which i use them as buttons to change a Main Panel's content which is layouted with a CardLayout.

[image]

I cant work perfectly with these events:

```
mouseEntered : to make highlight effect to the jlabel 
mouseExited  : to take off the highlight effect.
mouseClicked : to change the content of the main Panel and start some threads
```

The problem here that can't found an event or a method tell me that another Jlabel has been clicked so i can stop my threads started in the mouseClicked event,

**OR**

an event or method tell me that a JPanel in the CardLayout has been displayed or hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not finding an appropriate event. I think you are doing this using a visual GUI builder and expect to solve everything out-of-the-box. It's not going to work that way, you will need to write some real code. For example, write a method that you will call from the mouse click listener of each of the three JLabels. Thus you will have arranged for this method to be called for each JLabel click. Then in the method do the appropriate handling. This is just a rough outline, you haven't provided much detail to give any further advice.

Comment: No i'm working with no GUI builder, its not a problem of expecting to solve everything out-of-the-box, i'm just wondering if there is such events to handled just to make it easy. i have already write a method as u say, but its not help since i'm refactoring my code in multiple class (a class for every Card).

Comment: Are you then looking for a global event, perhaps? One that would fire whatever gets clicked anywhere inside a container? I believe there is no such event in the AWT/Swing framework, in contrast to JavaScript/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need `FocusEvents` and `FocusListeners`. These are supported by all `JComponents` like `JPanel`, `JLabel`, and `JButton`, such as by calling `addFocusListener();`

Basically a `FocusListener` can tell you when a `JComponent` gains focus (such as by clicking on the `JComponent`) and when it looses focus (such as by clicking on a different `JComponent`).

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html for further information

Comment: thanks, but its not helping because when the Jlabel1 (for example) gain focus he can loose him by clicking in the main Panel, and that's not what i want.